# react-bootstrap breadcrumb with react-router-dom changing background colour

Tags: reactjs, react-router, background-color, react-bootstrap, breadcrumbs

I want to change the background colour when using react-bootstrap breadcrumb.
at the same time I used the react-router-dom to implement the breadcrumb

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import { Breadcrumb, BreadcrumbItem } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default (props = {}) => {
    const items = props.items.map(item => (item.active ?
        <BreadcrumbItem active>{item.name}</BreadcrumbItem>
        :
        <BreadcrumbItem>
            <Link to={item.href}>
                {item.name}
            </Link>
        </BreadcrumbItem>
    ));
    return (
        <Breadcrumb>{items}</Breadcrumb>
    );
};
```

now the colour is #f5f5f5
I want to change it as #ffffff;

```
    .breadcrumb {
    padding: 8px 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

This is from chrome developer tools. That is what I want.
How can I write the css file, and where should I put the css file in ? to rewrite the default colour #f5f5f5 .

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

In a react app, the global style is in App.css file (Or even Index.css file). You could put that style in there if you want it to be a global style. If you want it to be a local style, you could simply add an inline style to your component. like :

```
<Component style={{backgroundColor: "#fff"}} />
```

Just pay attention that the inline styling should follow the rule of JSX styling.